# Sonar runner Exception

Tags: gradle, sonar-runner

While running sonarunner in gradle I am getting below exception:

> Execution failed for task ':sonarRunner'.
>   Fail to request server version

I am running below command from command line:

gradle clean build sonarRunner -

> Dsonar.host.url=http://srvsentdev01.lhs-systems.com:9000/ 
>   -Dsonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://srvsentdev01.lhs-systems.com/sonarqube -Dsonar.jdbc.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver -Dsonar.jdbc.username=xxxxx -Dsonar.jdbc.password=xxxxxxxx

where I am going wrong?

Comment: I am still stuck in this issue...does anybody has faced this issue ever? Help needed.

Comment: Try running the gradle command with --debug and look for a stack trace.  The basic issue is gradle cannot reach the sonar server - make sure you don't have firewall or proxy issues.  HTH

Comment: I tried using debug and getting below error: 08:38:12.590 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://hostname:9000/api/server/version   What could be the issue here? Is something missing in my build.gradle?

Comment: Sonar runner gradle task is not compatible with sonar 4.4. The issue is fixed in gradle 2.2-rc1. For now you can downgrade Sonar to 3.7 and it should work. More info here: http://forums.gradle.org/gradle/topics/sonar_runner_gradle_task_is_not_compatible_with_sonar_4_4

Comment: I also had success with Sonar 4.3.1.